# How to find the sum of n odd integers starting from 1?

Tags: php, algorithm, sum, integer

Today I had an interview and I had no idea how to answer this question...

> Give a recursive algorithm finding the sum of the first `n` odd positive integers.

For Example:

If `n=3` then the positive integers are `1+3+5` with a sum of `9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursion is unnecessary overhead, but this satisfies the requirements:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54b056a975c9acc6dd30bd1407cb4e03b1b41db0))

```
function sum_recursive($n){
    return ($n<<1)-1 + ($n>1 ? sum_recursive($n-1) : 0);
}

$number_of_odd_numbers=range(1,10);  // test cases
foreach($number_of_odd_numbers as $n){  // iterate test cases
    echo "$n => " , sum_recursive($n) , "\n";
}
```

Function Logic:

- Because `$n` is always `1` or more, no safeguards are in place to check for `0`.
- On every recursive call, use the [shift left bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) (for best performance) to multiply `$n` by `2` (once) then subtract 1, and add that number to the recursive call's return value.
- When `$n` is decremented down to `1`, cease the recursion and add `0` to the calculation.

Output:

```
1 => 1
2 => 4
3 => 9
4 => 16
5 => 25
6 => 36
7 => 49
8 => 64
9 => 81
10 => 100
```

---

Question requirements aside, a pure arithmetic method will be very fast and brief to code  (as few as 5 characters a la new school style):

```
pow($n,2)  // pow() is the old-school call

$n**2  // is new-school
```

Implementation: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09d4252b439fc30faa3fd46fd9d892578c64d671))

```
$number_of_odd_numbers=range(1,10);  // test cases

foreach($number_of_odd_numbers as $n){  // iterate test cases
    echo "$n => " , pow($n,2) , "\n";
    //    ^^-input  ^^^^^^^^^--- square $n
}
```

Output:

```
1 => 1     // 1
2 => 4     // 1,3
3 => 9     // 1,3,5
4 => 16    // 1,3,5,7
5 => 25    // 1,3,5,7,9
6 => 36    // 1,3,5,7,9,11
7 => 49    // 1,3,5,7,9,11,13
8 => 64    // 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15
9 => 81    // 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17
10 => 100  // 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19
```